# Cannot create folder inside Azure containers using azure-storage-file-datalake

Tags: python, azure, azure-storage, azure-data-lake-gen2

While I'm able to create containers using `azure-storage-file-datalake`, getting the following error during creation of folder inside the container -  `<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f5934d12250>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known`.

Note - I'm using azure databricks service to create containers on azure storage and folders inside of the container. create_directory() - is the function which is giving me this error.

```
!pip install azure-storage-file-datalake
```

```
import os, uuid, sys
from azure.storage.filedatalake import DataLakeServiceClient
from azure.core._match_conditions import MatchConditions
from azure.storage.filedatalake._models import ContentSettings
```

```
def initialize_storage_account(storage_account_name, storage_account_key):
    try:  
        global service_client

        service_client = DataLakeServiceClient(account_url="{}://{}.dfs.core.windows.net".format(
            "https", storage_account_name), credential=storage_account_key)
    
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

```
initialize_storage_account("storage-acc-name", "storage-acc-access-key")
```

```
def create_file_system():
    try:
        global file_system_client

        file_system_client = service_client.create_file_system(file_system="my-file-system")
    
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

```
create_file_system()
```

```
def create_directory():
    try:
        file_system_client.create_directory("my-directory")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

```
create_directory()
```

Comment: This works fine after reproducing from my end. Can you let me know in which environment are you executing this.

Comment: I'm using azure databricks to execute the above code. service_client is working fine and I can list all available containers in my storage account but during creation of folder inside a particular container I'm getting this error. I have even tried it with and without office VPN, every time I got the same.